# Set maximum and minimum width of div during re-size

Tags: javascript, css

Sorry for the ambiguous title, not sure how to phrase it.

I have an html page that has 2 iframes side by side with 100% height. I'm trying to set the maximum width of the iframe on right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>    
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">
          <div id="holder_Iframe1">
            <iframe id="iframe1" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz"></iframe>
            <div id="drag"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="holder_Iframe2">
            <iframe id="iframe2" src="http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mercedes?s=t"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>    
    </html>
```

Both iframes are wrapped by divs. Hover the mouse between the iframes to be see the re-size cursor.

I'm setting a maximum width of the iframe2 (the one on the right) of 560px, but when resizing, sometimes it passes that maximum width so I can't resize it back. I'm trying to fix that.

```
function Resize(e) {

      var rightPanePx = document.documentElement.clientWidth - parseInt(holder_Iframe1.style.width, 10);
      console.log(rightPanePx);
      if ((rightPanePx >= 25) && (rightPanePx <= 560)) {

        holder_Iframe1.style.width = (e.clientX - holder_Iframe1.offsetLeft) + "px";
        iframe1.style.width = Math.max((holder_Iframe1.style.width.replace("px", "") - 4), 0) + "px";

        holder_Iframe2.style.width = (document.documentElement.clientWidth - holder_Iframe1.style.width.replace("px", "")) + "px";
        iframe2.style.width = holder_Iframe2.style.width;

      }
    }
```

I have attached the code that demonstrates my problem.

```js
var iframe1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");
var iframe2 = document.getElementById("iframe2");
var holder_Iframe1 = document.getElementById("holder_Iframe1");
var holder_Iframe2 = document.getElementById("holder_Iframe2");
var dragEl = document.getElementById("drag");

holder_Iframe1.style.width = (Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) * 0.8) + "px";
iframe1.style.cssText = 'width:' + ((Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) * 0.8) - 5) + 'px;height:100%;';

dragEl.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  //create overlay so we will always get event notification even though the pointer is hovering iframes
  var overlay = document.createElement('div');
  overlay.id = "overlay";
  document.body.insertBefore(overlay, document.body.firstChild);

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', Resize, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize, false);
}, false);

function Resize(e) {

  var rightPanePx = document.documentElement.clientWidth - parseInt(holder_Iframe1.style.width, 10);
  console.log(rightPanePx);
  if ((rightPanePx >= 25) && (rightPanePx <= 560)) {

    holder_Iframe1.style.width = (e.clientX - holder_Iframe1.offsetLeft) + "px";
    iframe1.style.width = Math.max((holder_Iframe1.style.width.replace("px", "") - 4), 0) + "px";

    holder_Iframe2.style.width = (document.documentElement.clientWidth - holder_Iframe1.style.width.replace("px", "")) + "px";
    iframe2.style.width = holder_Iframe2.style.width;

  }
}

function stopResize(e) {
  //remove event listeners from improved performance
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', Resize, false);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopResize, false);

  //remove fake overlay
  document.getElementById("overlay").remove();
}
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
}
iframe,
#holder_Iframe1,
#holder_Iframe2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
}
#content-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
#content {
  display: table-row;
}
#holder_Iframe1,
#holder_Iframe2 {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 0 !important;
}
#holder_Iframe1 {
  width: 80%;
}
#drag {
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  cursor: col-resize;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  float: right;
}
#drag:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
#drag:active {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="holder_Iframe1">
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz"></iframe>
        <div id="drag"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="holder_Iframe2">
        <iframe id="iframe2" src="http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mercedes?s=t"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use cursor's position to detect where the direction is.

By adding `e.pageX` to your function to determine whether resize it or not.

In your sample this may be if `(window_size - e.pageX < 560)` go resize it, otherwise don't resize.